# Can't add json in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm beginner in reactjs and I'm trying import JSON file in my js. When I execute the.js with JSON (like in example but replace what is in the comment by the four first var) everything works but when I'm try to import from another file I have this Error. "TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function".

First

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
//import people from './db/dab.json';

var fs = require('fs');
var filname = '/db/dab.json';
var data = fs.readFileSync(filname, 'utf-8');
var people = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(people);

/*var people = [
    {
        "id": "johnson",
        "first_name": "Karol",
        "last_name": "Johnson",
        "rank":"1",            
    },
    {
        "id": "smith",
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "rank":"2",        
]*/

function searchingFor(term){
    return function (x) {
        return x.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()) || x.last_name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()) || x.birth_city.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()) ||  x.address.address1.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase());
    }
}

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            people: people,
            term:'',
        }
        this.searchHandler = this.searchHandler.bind(this);
    }

    searchHandler(event){
        this.setState({ term: event.target.value})
    }

    render() {
        const {term, people} = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <form>
                    <input type="texte"
                           onChange={this.searchHandler}
                           value={term}
                    />
                </form>
                {
                    people.filter(searchingFor(term)).map( person =>
                        <div key={person.id}>
                            <h3>{person.rank}</h3>

                    )
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 2):

The client-side apps (the ones that execute in a browser) doesn't have access to your file system, so you would have to import the file directly. This can only happen if the file is already in the file system when the app execute.

With this said the way to do it is as follows.

```
import people from './db/dab.json';
people = JSON.parse(people);
```

Comment: But in your example people is read only

Comment: Oh, so you want to modify the json of your file system? You should create a server and update the file through an HTTP request. If you use node as backend you could use the fs library. You can start from here https://alligator.io/nodejs/express-basics/ and create a simple express server and define a post method where you include all you logic that modifies the json. And on the client side you could use axios to make the request and pass the people object as a parameter. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If this is taking place in your browser, then you won’t have access to `fs` which is limited to server-side NodeJS. You’ll just access the JSON through web apis or `window.fetch()` and then just `JSON.parse(data)` to get access to it as a JS object.

Comment: I don't understand so what I need to do for test in my browser?

Comment: Probably ship the JSON file as an asset and access it via `fetch(‘assetPath’).then(response => doStuff())`. Here’s info on the fetch API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: You can import it directly without doing a fetch

Comment: @LuisGurmendez so can you say me do that?

Comment: Yeah, I read that in your original question. You can’t use fs. Did you read Luis’ answer?

Comment: yes so I remove fetch but what I need add for replace fs?

Comment: Luis’ answer is completely correct, you only need those two lines.